# Possible to Access Android Smart Phone Keystore?

Tags: java, android, certificate, keystore

Is it possible to access a android phones Keystore in some way?
I'm looking to be able to view some Application certificates.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want to access to System keystore, User keystore, or use Android Keystore?. What is the purpose?

Comment: to be honest, i really dont know wich keystore it is, what i do know is; that using an app, it creates specific certificates for users to that app. So i want to know if it is possible to view that certificate.. the only places i can view certificates right now is the CA certificates in Stored Credentials. And in the "User" tab its empty. so it must be some hidden keystore i guess... @pedrofb

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html _Use the Android Keystore provider to let an individual app store its own credentials that only the app itself can access._

Comment: I am sorry for asking this question but: If i can't see it from the phone, I cant or by design shouldn't be able access or view it? 

Is that how i should interpret that? The application is using a Android Keystore provider and NOT a keychain, which means that only the app that creates the credential should be able to see it or use it? @pedrofb

Thanks for your quick answers btw. :)

Comment: I deduce that if the application is creating and using certificates and you can not view them in the System keystore, then it is using AndroidKeystore

Comment: Ok. but hat does that mean, can i access the certificate or not?
Sorry but it's still a bit diffuse to me. @pedrofb

Comment: No, you can't. Certificates/keys created in AndroidKeystore are only accesible by the app that created them

Comment: Thank you very much for you answeres @pedrofb :)

Comment: Happy to help! I posted a summary as answer

Comment: @pedrofb, Hi sorry to bother you again, but just so i cover all my angles of approchering this, is there anyway to intercept the certificate via some type of call or even request it via some kind of endpoint? In a good or non-hacking way.. i'm developing an app around the app i'm trying to get the certificate from and i'm just wondering if i need to tackle this problem from another angle.

Comment: Does that app have an API? If not, you will not be able to use the private key of its certificate. The public part could be available because it does not incur any security risk and is probably available on some server, but you can not intercept the calls from app to server if using SSL, so you need to know where it is. Without knowing the application it is not possible to answer.

Comment: Ok, again thanks alot,, well the application is Windows authenticator app in android. I can see the Certificate in apple IOS and in a windows 10 phone but not in android. if you have any suggestions please you are welcome to tell me.  That gave me at least a line to pull away at the entanglement of the problem. If not i have another idea i think :)
I wish you the best @pedrofb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android KeyChain stores system-wide credentials. If the application is creating and using certificates and there are not visible in the System keystore, then it is probably using [AndroidKeystore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html)

> **Use the Android Keystore provider to let an individual app store its own credentials that only the app itself can access.** This provides a way for apps to manage credentials that are usable only by itself while providing the same security benefits that the KeyChain API provides for system-wide credentials.

You can not access to certificates/keys created by other app in AndroidKeystore. They are only accesible by the app that created them

Comment: Thanks for that nice Sum-up! :)